# Apache Ignite to Amazon S3 connectivity

Tags: ignite

I want to know how to load data from Amazon S3 to an Apache Ignite cluster? Would single node or multi node cluster required?

Comment: Did you find an existing solution, or did you have to write your own connector?

Comment: I would use spark + ignite which is way lot easier, https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/85af9c789a109f7f067145972a82693c7d28b4a9/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/IgniteDataFrameWriteExample.scala#L74

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/85af9c789a109f7f067145972a82693c7d28b4a9/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/IgniteDataFrameWriteExample.scala#L89

Answer (score 0):

You can load data to any cluster, single node or multi node, as long as your data set fits in memory of this cluster. Please refer to this documentation page for information about data loading: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/data-loading

Answer (score 0):

you can use Spark + Ignite as a workaround, spark to read S3 and then write to ignite as explained in the Ignite examples.

Also, you can use spark structured streaming trigger once just to write incremental files to Ignite, combine spark structured streaming and ignite.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/22/running-streaming-jobs-day-10x-cost-savings.html

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/85af9c789a109f7f067145972a82693c7d28b4a9/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/IgniteDataFrameWriteExample.scala#L74

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/85af9c789a109f7f067145972a82693c7d28b4a9/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/IgniteDataFrameWriteExample.scala#L89

Not sure whether sparK overwrites ignite tables workaround would be to create data frame on existing ignite data and union all latest data and then overwrite ignite table.

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/85af9c789a109f7f067145972a82693c7d28b4a9/examples/src/main/spark/org/apache/ignite/examples/spark/IgniteDataFrameWriteExample.scala#L113